# Angular8 - Como remover um <style> de uma <div> pela sua classe?

Tags: angular-8

Estou usando uma biblioteca chamada angular-gauge-chart pra inserir um gŕafico de gauge na minha aplicação.

Ela funciona perfeitamente, porém, ela possui alguns estilos, como style='350px', que são default e eu não consigo configurar.

Eu poderia alterar esse estilo diretamente no node-modules, mas isso seria incorreto e improdutivo.

O que eu preciso é: 
Ao inicializar e renderizar o componente, que seja removida o style **style="width: 350px;"** que está na  div que possui a classe **gauge-chart**

Este style eu não consigo configurar nas inbound properties do angular.

***Objetivo:***

Pelo virtual DOM, utilizando a classe **ElementRef** eu consigo remover esse style? Eu realmente estou tendo dificuldades para achar material que ensine como fazer isso.**

O que eu quero, em com JQuery, seria isso:

`$(".gauge-chart").removeAttr('style');`

Como fazer isso no angular?

**gauge-score.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-gauge-score",
  templateUrl: "./gauge-score.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./gauge-score.component.sass"]
})
export class ScoreDebtorsComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() dashboardData: any;
  public dashData: any = "";
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.dashboardData.previousValue) {
      this.dashData = this.dashboardData;
    }
  }

  public canvasWidth = 400;
  public needleValue = 100;
  public hasNeedle = false;
  public centralLabel = "14%";
  public name = "Gauge chart";
  public bottomLabel = "25";
  public options = {
    hasNeedle: false,
    needleValue: "14%",
    needleColor: "gray",
    needleUpdateSpeed: 1000,
    arcColors: ["rgb(44, 151, 222)", "lightgray"],
    arcDelimiters: [99],
    rangeLabel: ["0%", "100%"],
    needleStartValue: 50
  };
}
```

**gauge-score.component.html**

```
<div class="support-dashboard">
  <div class="flex-card support-box light-bordered has-text-centered">
    <h3 class="box-title has-text-centered">
      Score
    </h3>
    <div class="ring-title has-text-centered">
      <rg-gauge-chart
        [canvasWidth]="canvasWidth"
        [needleValue]="needleValue"
        [centralLabel]="centralLabel"
        [options]="options"
        [bottomLabel]="bottomLabel"
      ></rg-gauge-chart>
    </div>
    <div class="ring-title has-text-centered">
      <span [ngStyle]="{ color: '#5e6d75' }"
        >cadastre mais emails e telefones para melhorar o seu score</span
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**html renderizado** Abaixo o style que eu quero remover.

```
<div _ngcontent-kgc-c7="" class="gauge-chart" style="width: 350px;">
```